# Adding multiple audio tracks and subtitles to dash manifest (mpd) with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, manifest, mpeg-dash, mpd

I'm trying to create a website to stream some videos. For each video, I extract video, audio and subtitles in 3 different folders. It happens that a video has multiple audio tracks and multiple subtitles. I did a lot of research and I don't know how to add all of them in the manifest. Right now, I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -f webm_dash_manifest \
-i video1.mp4 -f webm_dash_manifest \
-i video2.mp4 -f webm_dash_manifest \
-i audio1.webm -f webm_dash_manifest \
-i audio2.webm -f webm_dash_manifest \
-i subtitles.vtt \
-c copy -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 \
-f webm_dash_manifest -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" manifest.mpd
```

My two videos have different resolutions and bitrates, and it works perfectly. But I don't get any subtitles and my two audio tracks are considered like one same audio track which has two different bitrates (just like videos). I think I should have many adaptation_sets, but I don't know how to create them.

How can I create that manifest the right way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a few days, I found the solution.

My goal is to convert a video into mpeg-dash content which is really great for streaming.

I will encode video to h264, audio to aac, and subtitles to webvtt.
It's good settings for a large browser compatibility.
vp9 is really nice too but too long to encode for me.

**Tools required:**

- ffmpeg: https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html
- mp4dash & mp4fragment: https://www.bento4.com/downloads/

---

Let's suppose we have a 1080p video file "video.mkv" with these streams:

- 0: video stream
- 1: audio stream, it language
- 2: audio stream, en langugage
- 3: subtitle stream, it language
- 4: subtitle stream, en language

## 1. Extracting differents streams

### 1.1 Video

I extract and transcode video stream to differents resolutions and bitrates:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -an -sn -c:0 libx264 -x264opts 'keyint=24:min-keyint=24:no-scenecut' -b:v 5300k -maxrate 5300k -bufsize 2650k -vf 'scale=-1:1080' tmp/video/video-1080.mp4

ffmpeg -i video.mkv -an -sn -c:0 libx264 -x264opts 'keyint=24:min-keyint=24:no-scenecut' -b:v 2400k -maxrate 2400k -bufsize 1200k -vf 'scale=-1:720' tmp/video/video-720.mp4

ffmpeg -i video.mkv -an -sn -c:0 libx264 -x264opts 'keyint=24:min-keyint=24:no-scenecut' -b:v 600k -maxrate 600k -bufsize 300k -vf 'scale=-1:360' tmp/video/video-360.mp4
```

### 1.2 Audio

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:1 -ac 2 -ab 192k -vn -sn tmp/audio/audio-it.mp4

ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:2 -ac 2 -ab 192k -vn -sn tmp/audio/audio-en.mp4
```

### 1.3 Subtitle

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:3 -vn -an tmp/subtitle/subtitle-it.vtt
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:4 -vn -an tmp/subtitle/subtitle-en.vtt
```

You can use the "-loglevel warning" option to see less informations.

## 2. Fragment video and audio

### 2.1 Video

```
mp4fragment tmp/video/video-1080.mp4 tmp/video/f-video-1080.mp4
mp4fragment tmp/video/video-720.mp4 tmp/video/f-video-720.mp4
mp4fragment tmp/video/video-360.mp4 tmp/video/f-video-360.mp4
```

### 2.2 Audio

```
mp4fragment tmp/audio/audio-it.mp4 tmp/audio/f-audio-it.mp4
mp4fragment tmp/audio/audio-en.mp4 tmp/audio/f-audio-en.mp4
```

## 3. Split files and create the dash manifest

```
mp4dash --mpd-name=manifest.mpd tmp/video/f-video-1080.mp4 tmp/video/f-video-720.mp4 tmp/video/f-video-360.mp4 tmp/audio/f-audio-it.mp4 tmp/audio/f-audio-en.mp4 \[+format=webvtt,+language=it\]tmp/subtitle/subtitle-it.vtt \[+format=webvtt,+language=en\]tmp/subtitle/subtitle-en.vtt
```

You can now delete the tmp folder

```
rm -rf tmp
```

(and your source file if you don't need it anymore)

You have now your mpeg-dash content which can be streamed. You have to serve your files (allow cors and enable byte range request).
I use angular and rx-player as player. I can switch language, subtitles and the video quality is adaptative to the client's bandwidth !

Rx-player: https://github.com/canalplus/rx-player