# How to use multiple subtitles in DASH manifest in Google Transcoder

Tags: google-cloud-transcoder

I tried reading there documentation but it's showing example only for HLS format for multiple subtitle files.

If i do the same as HLS example for DASH. It's giving the following error.
`Containers other than mp4 or fmp4 are not supported in DASH manifest`

Comment: Hi @billa-code, As per this [document](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/captions-and-subtitles#add-subtitles), subtitles are only supported in HLS manifests and are not supported in DASH manifests or MP4 files. Also please have a look at this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494814/adding-multiple-audio-tracks-and-subtitles-to-dash-manifest-mpd-with-ffmpeg), it might help you.

Comment: @DhirajSingh subtitles are supported in DASH manifests, problem is with multiple subtitles. If you look at the previous example in same document, it works. And the stack overflow link you posted doesnt help. Tried it before and google transcoder api give an error when using multiple text streams in same job

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: Created feature request upon contacting support team